# Property Foreign Key can not be set to NULL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have 4 tables

```
public class StokGroup:BaseModel
{
     public string GroupName { get; set; }
     public List<GroupFeature> GroupFeatures { get; set; }
     public List<StokCard> StokCards { get; set; }
}
public class GroupFeature : BaseModel
{
     public int StokGroupId { get; set; } 
     public StokGroup StokGroup { get; set; }
     public string FeatureName { get; set; }
     public List<StokCardAdditionalFeatureValue> StokCardAdditionalFeatureValues { get; set; }

}
public class StokCard : BaseModel
{
     public string IPMCode { get; set; }
     public int StokGroupId { get; set; }
     public StokGroup StokGroup { get; set; }
     .......................................
}
public class StokCardAdditionalFeatureValue:BaseModel
{
    public int StokCardId { get; set; }
    public StokCard StokCard { get; set; }
    public int GroupFeatureId { get; set; }
    public GroupFeature GroupFeature { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

}
```

And my BaseModel is the class that has Primary Key ID all classes inherit from BaseModel

```
public class BaseModel
{
     [Key] 
      public int Id { get; set; }
        
}
```

And I have also :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StokCard>()
.HasOne(o => o.StokGroup)
.WithMany(m => m.StokCards)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

modelBuilder.Entity<GroupFeature>()
.HasOne(o => o.StokGroup)
.WithMany(m => m.GroupFeatures);

modelBuilder.Entity<StokCardAdditionalFeatureValue>()
.HasOne(o => o.StokCard)
.WithMany(m => m.StokCardAdditionalFeatureValues)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

modelBuilder.Entity<StokCardAdditionalFeatureValue>()
.HasOne(o => o.GroupFeature)
.WithMany(m => m.StokCardAdditionalFeatureValues);
```

Now the problem is when the stokgroup is deleted StokCard is deleted automatically because of the relationship
How can I achieve this problem ?

I set NULL to StokGroupId on StokCards table but migration FAILED

Would you mind please help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't defined the FK properties to be Nullable, so how can they be #null? Start by making StokGroupId on StokCards an `int?` property.

Comment: I did that migration says Build Failed

Comment: EF should have provided you more information than just the fact that the migration failed...

Comment: How can I get more information about that ? Because when I change int? to int it works otherwise it says only build failed